# ldap_set_rebind_proc() function does not work in any PHP Windows distribution

Tags: php, ldap, php-extension

The  problem is:

ldap_set_rebind_proc() function does not work in any PHP Windows distribution

error obtained when executing the php file:
Undefined function ldap_set_rebind_proc()

PHP tested versions (5.* y 7.*), I've even tried it on PHP versions included in WAMP and XAMPP server.

The other LDAP PHP functions , like ldap_connect(), ldap_bind(), etc. works well.

ldap_set_rebind_proc() function works well on PHP Linux distributions.

Any idea of this bug? Any solution to read referrals responses of ldap_search() function without using ldap_set_rebind_proc()?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this issue on Windows server? I got the same one, may be you have found some good ideas on this case? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to compile PHP against a current version of OpenLDAP, though TBH I'm not sure how easy that is on Windows.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ldap/ldap.c#L4713), you will see the function is only defined if:

```
#if defined(LDAP_API_FEATURE_X_OPENLDAP) && defined(HAVE_3ARG_SETREBINDPROC)
```

These are both quite old features (like, turn of the century), but perhaps the prebuilt binaries are not compiled against modern versions.